# How did Luke and Obi Wan evade imperial troops in Mos Eisley Cantina?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

After the lighsaber fight in the cantina, Luke and Obi Wan sit at a table with Han and Chewie to negotiate passage to Alderaan.

Imperial troops enter the bar, Han says "looks like someone's interested in your handiwork...," and we see the troops moving around the bar towards the table.

When the camera pans back to the table, Luke and Obi Wan are gone.  Where did they go, and how did they do it without being seen by the stormtroopers?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They went out of the Cantina's back entrance.

> His new passengers turned to look, the kid about jumping out of his
> skin as the barkeep pointed toward them. It was left to Ben to drag
> the kid off into the shadows, pulling him toward **the back entrance**. By
> the time the stormtroopers looked again, they were gone.
>
> <sub><sup>[A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>

The next time we see them they've walked around the outside of the Cantina back to the front entrance where they meet up with C-3PO and R2-D2 who've been hiding in the 'Used Droid Lot'.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Inside the Worlds of Star Wars Trilogy**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Inside_the_Worlds_of_Star_Wars_Trilogy)</sup></sub>

Comment: So in addition to being unable to hit a target at point blank range, Storm Troopers don't know about blocking *all* the exits before searching a place ?  :-)

Comment: @StephenG It's a patrol. No different to a bar fight and the police arrive. The police, assuming they have the numbers, hang around the main door, they don't automatically establish a cordon around the bar. By the time they realise someone's dead it's too late to stop the killers, they're already gone.